# How to remove the ListPicker Header in Windows Phone 7 toolkit control?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is there any way to completely remove the header in the Windows Phone 7 control toolkit ListPicker? E.g., setting the header height size = 0 or something similar?

In my app I want to remove the header in order to reduce the space taken up by the list picker. I'm going to have the default selected item in the list picker with a descriptive text instead (along with a valid value of course). I've solved that part.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Download the source from here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/71382

Open up ListPickerPage.xaml (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit -> ListPicker)

Find this section of code:

```
<!-- Header Title -->
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="HeaderTitle"
            Grid.Row="0"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed"
            Margin="24 12 12 12">
            <TextBlock.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationX="-90"/>
            </TextBlock.Projection>
        </TextBlock>
```

Note that the Visibility is now set to Collapsed

Then, below it, find the ListBox code

```
 <!-- List of Items -->
        <ListBox
            x:Name="Picker"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            Opacity="0"
            toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
            Margin="24 -24 0 0" 
            Tap="OnPickerTapped"/>
    </Grid>
```

Note that I changed the margin here to -24.

Mess with it till you find the look that you need. Make sure you have your app use the DLL that is created when you build the Silverlight Toolkit project.

There could be a better way. For example, you could create your own `PickerPageUri` .

But, I'm not entirely sure that modifying the UI in this way to achieve another 40px of space is really worth breaking the WP7 paradigm. But whatever, your choice.